# iOS use dropbox longpool_delta api

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I'm trying to understand how to use and have back the right value from the dropbox longpool_delta api call. I successfully retrieve the cursor value but always get the 400 code as response. Can anyone help me to fix it or help me to understand where i'm wrong?
For quickly test i've setup the request with AFNetworking.
Below the sample code.
Thanks

```
NSString *myUrl = @"https://api.dropbox.com/1/delta/";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myUrl];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//here set the header with access token with oAuth2 api
[request setValue: [self headerForApiCall]  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
request.timeoutInterval = 90.0;
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

AFJSONRequestOperation * operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

NSString* cursor = JSON[@"cursor"];
NSString *myUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api-notify.dropbox.com/1/longpoll_delta/?cursor=%@",cursor];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myUrl];
NSMutableURLRequest *request2 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request2.timeoutInterval = 90.0;
[request2 setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

AFJSONRequestOperation * operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request2 success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

        NSLog(@"long %@",JSON);

} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {

NSLog(@"failure long %@",response.description);

}];

[operation start];



} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)    {
NSLog(@"failure %@",response.description);
}];

[operation start];
```

[edit]
As suggested here the response code 400 from the failure block

```
status code: 400, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Type" = "text/plain";
Date = "Wed, 14 May 2014 16:04:28 GMT";
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = nginx;
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-DB-Timeout" = 120;
}
```

removing `/` the response always from the failure block but with a (null) value

Comment: If @BoilingLime's answer isn't correct, please tell us the body of the 400 response. It should tell you the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Error 400 is from bad parameters, I think your problem is here :

```
NSString *myUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api-notify.dropbox.com/1/longpoll_delta/?cursor=%@",cursor];
```

Try to remove the `/` between `longpoll_delta` and `?` as follow :

```
NSString *myUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api-notify.dropbox.com/1/longpoll_delta?cursor=%@",cursor];
```

By the way should create a Dropbox HTTP client which will help you a lot to manage your request. Create a class which inherits from `AFHTTPClient`. your create a singleton as follow :

```
+ (DBAPIClient *)sharedClientWithBaseUrl:(NSString *)baseUrl {
static DBAPIClient *sharedInstance = nil;
static dispatch_once_t apiToken;
dispatch_once(&apiToken, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[DBAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.dropbox.com/1/"]];
    // Do any other initialisation stuff here
});
return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
if (!self) {
    return nil;
}

return self;
}
```

In this way you'll be able to use like this which is much more simple :

```
NSDictionary *params = // Your params;

[[DBPIClient sharedClient]
 getPath://the endpoint you want access to
 parameters:params
 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {

 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

 }];
```